# Sort by newest doesn't work on new profile page

Tags: support, bug

Previously below URL used to show profile page with answers sorted by "Newest". However this no longer works. This was useful because if you want to send URL of your profile page to someone, you might want the receiver see your latest answers rather than something that had been popular 5 years ago but irrelevant now.

Test URL:
https://stackoverflow.com/users/207661/shitalshah?tab=profile&sort=newest

Comment: As far I'm aware, the profile tab doesn't allow any kind of sorting. Are you looking for [activity](http://stackoverflow.com/users/207661/shitalshah?tab=topactivity)

Comment: To be more precise (and the OP will correct me if I misunderstood): You **can** sort the posts by "Newest". But there's no obvious way to get a URL that will directly open the profile with that tab selection.

Comment: +1 because causing pre-existing URLs to behave differently after an update is bad form.

Answer (score 1):

You're just looking at the wrong page. Rather than `tab=profile` you need to be on `tab=answers`. If you follow the url below you will see what you're after:

> https://stackoverflow.com/users/207661/shitalshah?tab=answers&sort=newest

Comment: I know it works for tab=answers. I'm saying it should also work for tab=profile because that page shows answers as part of profile with default sort. The reason this is important is because people would likely want to link to profile page than answers page but with answers sorted by newest for the reason I've mentioned in question.